# link error in gsl_complex_mul

Tags: c, gsl

I have started using gsl recenltly in a huge old C project. I have managed to add the libraries by adding the location in my system in **Properties>C/C++>General>Additional Include Directories**.

In my code, I am also including the following:

```
#include "gsl/gsl_matrix.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_matrix_complex_double.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_matrix_complex_float.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_matrix_complex_long_double.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_math.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_spmatrix.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_complex.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_complex_math.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_inline.h"
#include "gsl/gsl_complex.h"
```

I can now use most functions of gsl. but in the fowllowing function:

```
void vector_complex_mul_elements(gsl_vector_complex *v1, gsl_vector_complex *v2)
{
    gsl_complex cpx1, cpx2, cpx3;
    GSL_SET_COMPLEX(&cpx1, 0, 0);
    GSL_SET_COMPLEX(&cpx2, 0, 0);
    GSL_SET_COMPLEX(&cpx3, 0, 0);

    if(v1->size != v2->size)
    {
        printf("Error: Lenght of arrays do not match.\n");
        return;
    }

    for(i=0; i < v1->size; i++)
    {
        cpx1 = gsl_vector_complex_get(v1, i);
        cpx2 = gsl_vector_complex_get(v2, i);
        //cpx3 = gsl_complex_mul(cpx1 , cpx2);
        gsl_vector_complex_set(v1, i, cpx3);

    }
}
```

When I uncomment the line:

```
cpx3 = gsl_complex_mul(cpx1 , cpx2);
```

I get the following errors:

> Error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "_log1p".
>
> Error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "_log1p".
>
> Error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "_hypot".
>
> Error LNK1120: 2 unresolved external references.

I have already tried writing it like:

```
gsl_vector_complex_set(v1, i, gsl_complex_mul(cpx1 , cpx2));
```

Then I get these errors:

> Error LNK2019: Reference to unresolved external symbol "_log1p" in function "_gsl_complex_logabs".
>
> Error LNK2019: Reference to unresolved external symbol "_hypot" in function "_gsl_complex_div".
>
> Error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "_log1p".
>
> Error LNK1120: 2 unresolved external references.

Is this a only a linking problem or the way I am using it is wrong?

Comment: what is this `_log1p` and `_hypot`, is it belong to third party libraries? Make sure you're including the necessary header files and link it with correct libraries?.

Comment: I am not using them. I couldnt find _log1p at all in the whole project. and _hypot is in math.h. I am definetly not using it directly in mycode.

Comment: is `gsl_complex_mul` a macro?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

These (`lop1p` and `hypot`) functions are in the standard maths library. Are you including `math.h` and linking to it (`-lm`)? As per the [GSL documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linking-programs-with-the-library.html).

Comment: I am working with VS2010. I have included math.h but I don't know how I can link it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't work in VS2010. A quick search showed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571472/adding-a-library-to-visual-studio-2010-express) and [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Compiler/Linker/Libraries/Configuring_Visual_Studio).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are wrong linked GSL library. 
Try to rebuild GSL as a dll and relink it, as [I showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526274/assigning-complex-values-in-gsl/54410261#54410261) you in your other post.